# MapsForge render theme with coloured hiking trail

Tags: openstreetmap, mapsforge

I am looking for mapsforge render theme which displays hiking trails colours based on their waymarks colours (for example like on this server www.freemap.sk). I have found a lot of themes that displays this based on some kind of Alpine classification or based on local vs regional route (elevate theme does this) but none of them colours the trails based on waymark colour. Even locus on Android does this and it displays it correctly.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: you can use dy when :
`<rule e="way" k="colour" v="black">
<line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.9" dy="-1" stroke-linecap="butt" />
</rule>`